# Replay Javascript range styling to identical document in new session

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath

I am trying to record user selections and replay them in a new session at a later point in time. I cannot figure out how to re-create the range(s) the user has selected in the new session.

Specifically, I display (inside a div with a known ID) a blob of HTML. The user makes a selection and clicks a button. This allows me to capture whatever information I want about the range. I am using Rangy to get the range information and capture the start and end nodes and offsets, the raw HTML, and the text property. I also style the selection at this point, which obviously changes the DOM. The user may make/store multiple selections. When they click 'save' I upload all the selection data to the server and store it.

At a later point in time, a different user looks at the same blob of HTML (also inside a div with a known ID). The are presented with the document with all user-applied highlighting shown.

Obviously in a new session the DOM objects are different, so storing the actual node data is meaningless. I also tried converting the path to the node as an XPath but I can't find a good way to then re-apply the XPath to find the target node in the new session. I thought of counting elements to find the start or end element, but the count obviously changes if later selections come before previous selections and this will throw off the retrieval without some hairy logic.

Is there a good way to remember and re-find a node in a DOM that could change slightly (and in predictable ways)?

Comment: Have you looked at Rangy's Highlighter module?

Comment: I have, and I'm using it to apply highlights at the time the initial user selects an item. I don't see (or missed) if this has some mechanism for replaying those highlights at a later time in a different web session. Do you know of any documentation that shows how to accomplish this?

Comment: There are [`serialize()`](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Highlighter-Module#serializeselection-selection) and [`deserialize()`](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Highlighter-Module#serializeselection-selection) methods. The [demo page](http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/highlighter.html) uses them to persist highlights between page visits.

Comment: completely missed that when I read through the documentation the first time... that's fantastic. thanks! I will write-up an answer to this crediting you if/when I get it all working.

Comment: It's sort of working for what I need... I can serialize just fine but am having difficulty with deserialization. The page where deserialization happens is laid out a little differently, so the indexes aren't lining up (I think that's the issue). Is it possible to specify a base node from which the serialization and deserialization is rooted, similar to the doc parameter to createHighlighter but providing an element instead?

Comment: Not exactly, but you can restrict highlights to a container element by providing an element ID as an optional third parameter to `highlightSelection()`. This ID is then included in the serialized highlights and used when deserializing. I haven't documented this, it would seem. I will do so shortly.

Comment: Can you email me offline (email address is in my profile) so I can ask some clarifying questions? What I'm trying to do is a little more extensive than what Rangy was built for and I would like to extend it in a way that is consistent with your design goals. Thanks for your awesome module and your help on all this!

Comment: I can't immediately see your email address on your profile. Mine is pretty freely available (from my website, for example), so feel free to mail me.

Comment: Sent you an email, haven't heard anything... can you see if it fell to spam?

Comment: I've had the email. I'm getting to it soon :)

Comment: cool, sorry for the pestering then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Rangy 1.3 (still in beta at the time of this writing), you can preserve highlightings between sessions easily.

First initialize Rangy when your page loads:

```
var highlighter;
var highlightClass = "someCssClassName";

$(document).ready(function() {
    highlighter = rangy.createHighlighter();
    highlighter.addClassApplier(rangy.createCssClassApplier(highlightClass, {
        ignoreWhiteSpace: true,
        tagNames: ["span", "a"]
        }));
});
```

To highlight the text that is selected with a :

```
highlighter.highlightSelection(highlightClass);
```

To serialize all the highlighted text in the current document:

```
var data = highlighter.serialize();
storeDataToExternalSourceAndReloadPage(data);
```

To later (or in another session) deserialize the data object and highlight the current document:

```
var data = loadDataFromExternalSource();
highlighter.deserialize(data);
```

Easy! Thanks Tim for an amazingly helpful library!